# Fazer uma consulta SQL com Entity Framework 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Como faço pra realizar uma consulta no banco usando Entity Framework 4 passando uma *string* guardada previamente dentro de uma `StringBuilder`.

O motivo é que a string de consulta SQL é gigante. Sei que não é uma boa prática,mas por enquanto terei que fazer assim por falta de tempo hábil.

Essa é a *string* SQL da consulta:

```
StringBuilder strSql = new StringBuilder();
strSql.AppendLine(string.Format("SELECT * FROM (SELECT TOP intRestante * FROM (SELECT TOP {0}", intTop))[... Continua, a string é gigante];
```

Em WebForms eu faria algo assim:

```
objCommand = new SqlCommand();
objCommand.Connection = conn;
objCommand.CommandTimeout = 600;
objCommand.CommandText = strSql.ToString();
objCommand.Parameters.Add("@Parametros", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100).Value = "%" + strParametros + "%";
SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(objCommand);
adp.Fill(dt);
```

Gostaria de saber como fazer exatamente a mesma coisa, porém em Entity Framework.

Comment: Coloque o exemplo e um trecho do código isso pode ajudar a solucionar seu problema!

Comment: Se a `string` é muito grande, o correto é fragmentar a consulta única em várias consultas.

Comment: Cigano Morrison Mendez  Eu poderia fazer assim, mas a string já está pronta e "querem" que eu a use.

Comment: @JuniorDias Bom, então coloque a `string` toda aqui. Dar pra fazer, até dá, mas é péssimo usar desta forma.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez Eu já consegui aqui, usei o ctx.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand

Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para Entity Framework execução de comandos com query (que retorna de dados) , você precisa ter alguns tipos de dados definidos para o mapeamento do resultado da consulta.

Se você quiser resultados un-typed, eu sugiro que você use SqlConnection + DbCommand para executar a consulta e analisar o resultado via DbReader objeto.

Fonte: http://forums.asp.net/post/5367669.aspx